# Proving $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{k^a} > 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis

> How to prove $$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\frac{{\sin kx}}{{{k^a}}}}  > 0,x \in \left( {0,\pi } \right),a \in \left( {0,\frac{1}{2}} \right].$$

I have tried derivative，but it seems no use！Could anyone tell me the method
to obtain it?

**Background:** The problem is originated in the first homework of Fourier Analysis. One of the questions is to prove that the function $\sum \frac{\sin nx}{n^a}$ is not the Fourier series of an integrable function. Since Stein use "integrable" as the narrow means of Riemann integrable instead of Lebesgue integrable, but my homework doesn't show which kind of "integrable" the question mean.

Comment: @OmranKouba Sorry,we must change $n$ to $+\infty$!

Comment: What is the context in which you encountered this?

Comment: @Dr.MV I have added it in my problem. Thanks!

Comment: On the "Background;"  [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Statement_of_Parseval.27s_theorem) should clearly show that the series cannot represent any square integrable function.

Comment: This is the imaginary part of $$ \operatorname{Li}_\alpha\!\left(e^{ix}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^\alpha} $$ Plotting this in Mathematica, it looks to be true for $a\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

What about applying [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) and the [Fejer-Jackson inequality](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S1446788700000525)?

Despite integrability or square-integrability issues, such a series is pointwise convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since the partial sums of $\sin(kx)$ are bounded and $\frac{1}{k^a}$ is decreasing towards zero.